# How can i run the code of this link ?

Tags: mysql, database, netbeans, java-me, android-emulator

http://j2mesamples.blogspot.com/2009/02/database-connection-using-j2me.html

I'm using Netbeans IDE 7.0.1 and Xampp. Can you help me with step by step direction ?

Comment: the way i explain the answer... you tired that link as it ?

Answer (score 1):

It's very good example of MySql connectivity with J2ME. When I was doing database connectivity with Mysql, this was the first program I tried.

It is very simple, see first code is for Midlet, and the below code of class HttpServlet is Servlet, you need web server like [Apache Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) to run it.

Comment: ah! great . Can you help me out by describing step by step ?